# Xcode 5 (obj-c) + PHP + MySQLi: Cannot insert new entry into table through iOS simulator

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, xcode5

My goal here is to insert a new entry into my 'students' table when someone clicks 'Create Profile'.

So far I have attempted to do a NSMutableURLRequest to my PHP page using POST.

The application builds successfully, but it does not insert anything into the MySQL database.

```
- (IBAction)studentCreateSubmitButton:(id)sender {
    NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"studentCreateFirst=%@&studentCreateLast=%@&studentCreateUniversity=%@&studentCreateYear=%@&studentCreateMajor=%@",[self.studentCreateFirst text], [self.studentCreateLast text], [self.studentCreateUniversity text], [self.studentCreateYear text], [self.studentCreateMajor text]];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"cgi.soic.indiana.edu/~team14/student_insert2.php"]];


    NSLog(@"PostData: %@", post);


[request setHTTPBody:postData];

}
@end


<?php

echo "test1";


header('Content-type:');
   $con=mysqli_connect("db.soic.indiana.edu","caps15_team14","my+sql=caps15_team14","caps15_team14");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// prepare sql statement
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO    students(fname,lname,university,year,major) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssss', $_POST['studentCreateFirst'],
$_POST['studentCreateLast'],
$_POST['studentCreateUniversity'],
$_POST['studentCreateYear'],
$_POST['studentCreateMajor']);
$stmt->execute();
$newId = $stmt->insert_id;
$stmt->close();

echo "test2";


mysqli_close($con);
>?
```

Comment: What is the output of the NSLog statement with the Post response data? Also, is there anything being logged to your error log? (generally /var/log/apache2/error.log in a standard LAMP environment).

Comment: It was outputting in the NSLog successfully, like "StudentCreateFirst=John&StudentCreateLast=Smith&...